# How to change git origin back to local c9 workspace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, version-control, cloud9

I'm currently developing a web application on Heroku using cloud9 (c9.io) as a workspace.

As a result of a git mistake I have found that my origin repository is at the same location as my Heroku repository so changes I make in development are right away placed into production.

because my origin repository is the same as my Heroku repository using the command:

```
git push
```

is treated the same as

```
git push heroku
```

I understand the process of how to switch a repository to the origin, but I'm unsure where my c9 local repository was/is.

Does anyone know the location of c9's default git origin repository or know how to change c9 back to my origin repository?

EDIT:

c9 does not provids a git repository by default, i was using my heroku repository as origin the entire time, i acheived the behavior i desired by adding a bitbucket repo to origin. Sorry for the dumb question!

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please read the SO guidelines before posting.

Comment: What's the  output of `git remote -v`? Do you mean the local repo has two remotes: `origin` and `heroku`? And you can also check if you have `~/workspace` directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, C9 only provides you the development environment.  It does not include a special place to host your git repositories.

There is no way for anyone [other than you] to know where the 'origin' was initially.  Based on your description - and your reference to "a Github mistake" - I suspect you began with 'origin' referencing a repository in your GitHub account.